# Set and unpack array of objects in Azure Logic App parameters

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that is triggered by schedule (no incoming http request that I can retrieve variables from) and I want to set some parameters within this logic app that are retrieved within a `For each` block.
Each parameter that should be retrieved inside `For each` block is a tuple: `('foo', 'bar')`.
I was hoping to set these params in the logic app parameters as:

```
Name: MyConfigArray
Type: Array
Default Value: [('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'qux')]
```

But it throws `Enter a valid array` error.

I also want to be able to unpack each individual element inside `For each` block `Current item`. I'm looking for the best practice here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array of objects, the following syntax can be used: `[{"a":["foo","bar"]},{"a":["baz","qux"]}]`

To access individual values inside [`For each`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop) block, you can use an expression like this: `item().a[0]` - it would return "foo" and "baz".